# Angular POST not creating item

Tags: php, angular, typescript, rest, post

The structure of the files regarding the problem is the following:

*Note that the code inside isn't the whole file, just what I need to show.*

**tareas.component.html**

This is where I display the info, one button for every tarea + 1 that has `"(click)="crearTarea()"` inside it.

**tareas.component.ts**

```
crearTarea(){
if(this.data[0].length < 10){
  this._tarea.crearTarea().then(() => {
    this.ngOnInit();
  });
}else{
  alert("No se pueden crear mas tareas");
}
}
```

I want it to execute whenever the button is clicked as long as there are 10 tareas max. I call ngOnInit() afterwards because inside it there is a read() method to update the tareas the user sees.

Note that _tarea is the TareasService.

**tareas.service.ts**

```
crearTarea(){
    let parametros = new HttpParams()
      .set("command", "create")
      .set("userId", JSON.stringify(this.verification.user));
    
    let tarea = {
        id: "",
        usuario_id: this.verification.user,
        hecha: 0,
        imagen_url: "TODO"
      };
    
    return this.http.post
    (this.url, tarea, {params: parametros, withCredentials : true, responseType : "blob"})
    .toPromise();
  }
```

The first parameters is a string just to select which action to do inside the php's switch. I create a new Tarea* and make post request to the php file. With the post request I have to set the params that I wrote before along with `withCredentials: true` (not sure if this one is needed but I did need it for the update) and `responseType: blob` (I think text also works).

*Not an object Tarea itself because since the DB id has autoincrement, I have to set `id=""` and since id is a number in the interface, it won't let me create a Tarea without it. However that's not the problem, I can just pass the data in json which is what I've been doing with the Update.

**tarea.php**

```
case "create":
      if(isset($_GET["userId"])){
    
        $userId = $_GET["userId"];
        
          $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
          $request = json_decode($postdata);
          $tareaId = $request->id;
          $hecha = $request->hecha;
          $imagenUrl = $request->imagen_url;

          $error =  checkUser($userId) &&
                    checkDatosCorrectos($imagenUrl, $hecha);
    
          if($error){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tareas(id, usuario_id, hecha, imagen_url) VALUES ('', $userId, $hecha, $imagenUrl)";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    
          }else{
            print("No se cumplen los requisitos");
          }
      }else{
        print("User id not set");
      }

      break;
```

Finally, in the php I first check that $userId is set. Then I dump the post data inside vars (can't make a vardump because $_POST doesnt work since PHP doesn't allow JSON inside $_POST). Aftwerwards I make a couple checks which make sure everything is ok (they are working just fine, checked it with `echo()`) and if it passes the checks, it finally makes the query.

**Now the problem:** somehow, everything is working fine but the button does pretty much nothing. I placed a few console.logs around to isolate the error and so far, the new tarea (the one in the service) is fine, the query works perfect when done within PHPMyAdmin and it makes the whole cycle, but at the end, there are no new tareas, so even if there are no errors, I'm thinking that the php might not be "executing" (it does go inside the file and makes every step, but the query isnt executed). If I were dealing with an Observable it would probably need a `.subscribe()`, but since I'm dealing with a Promise I don't know what to do.

On top of that, I have an update method which works almost the same (instead of creating the tarea in the service, I get the tarea from the html -> ts -> service) and that one does work, so I don't know whats wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I didn't post all the console.logs() I have all around the code in order to check wether the code enters an area or not to make it clearer, but since it looks like it might help here it goes. I have a console.log() in:

**tarea.component.ts - crearTarea() :**

1. When it enters the if
2. Inside the promise before the ngOnInit()

**tarea.service.ts - crearTarea() :**

3. When it enters the method
4. After the custom params have been set
5. After the custom tarea has been initialized + it's values

**tareas.php - inside "create" case:**

(this ones are echo() and are just visible whenever I get an error, for example if I change responseType to json)

6. After the userId is setted
7. After the data "dump" + all vars values
8. After passing the checks + $error value
9. After entering the if($error) - (so it means validation went as expected)
10. After mysqli_query() is executed

When I said it did a whole cycle I meant that it goes through every console.log and echo. The order would be the following:

1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> ** -> 2

** would be the echo() in the php file which would go in order, from 6 to 10

Hope that this helps to narrow where the error might be.

Comment: Try to insert a console.log() inside your promise, does it appear in the console?

Comment: @JackyShows I can't write [...].toPromise(console.log()); it's not a valid param for toPromise()

Comment: I meant here: this._tarea.crearTarea().then(() => {
   console.log('test'); this.ngOnInit();
  });

Comment: Oooh allright sorry, I'm new to Angular and I'm still learning the ropes. Yeah I had a console.log there (I actually have a bunch but I didn't post it i the code to make it clearer) and it goes through aswell. Let me edit the answer in order to clarify where are those console.logs